# Removing the 'log out' link from devise's sign_up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a partial that holds a link to log out and I rendered it in the application.html.erb, so now it appears in every page, but I don't want that link to appear in the sign up page because obviously users are not signed up yet so they cants sign out, how should I go about that? Override devise controllers ?

Thanks

Comment: override views and remove the link

Comment: The link comes from a partial thats rendered inside application.html.erb not from the devise views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to the "logout" link

Assuming you are just using erb templates,

```
<%unless current_user.nil?%>
   <%= link_to "Sign Out", ...%>
<%end%>
```